# Expected size of the maximal prime gap below x under Hardy-Littlewood conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $ \pi_{n}(x) $ denote the number of prime gaps of size  $ n $ below  $ x $ for even  $ n $. The Hardy-Littlewood conjecture predicts that  $ \pi_{n}(x)\sim C_{n}\frac{x}{\log^{2}x} $ with  $ C_{n}=C_{2}\prod_{q\mid n}\frac{(q-1)}{(q-2)} $,  $ C_{2}=0.66016... $ is the so called twin prime constant and  $ q $ runs among odd primes dividing  $ n $. Let  $ Q_{a,b}(x) $ be the largest primorial not exceeding  $ x^{a}\log^{b} x $.

Assuming the conjecture above, can we determine  $ a $ and  $ b $ so that  $ \pi_{Q_{a,b}(x)}(x)\asymp 1 $ as  $ x $ tends to  $ \infty $?